# How to prove the mean value theorem for a function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ where $D\subseteq \mathbb{E}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{E}^n$ be an open and convex set and suppose $f \in C^1(D,\mathbb{R})$. Prove the Mean Value Theorem: Given $x,y \in D$ there is a point $c\in D$ on the line segment joining $x$ and $y$ such that 
$$f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(x-y)$$
(Hint: Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to D$ be given by $g(t) = ty +x(1-t)$ and consider the function $f \circ g)$

Comment: Can I only show that $f\circ g$ is continuous and differentiable? Since $f\circ g$ is really going from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{E}$ mean?

Comment: @T.Haddad It means 1-dimensional Eulidean space.

Comment: @user3000482 basically that is it.